# Can I ask a question about P2P networking as long as it's coding related?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am trying to ask a question about implementing a P2P network in Python. I wish to ask something like this:

> I am trying to create a P2P network in Python. However, there is a problem: Once a new user opens their application, how do they locate the network? I don't want a centralized IP distribution website, but I don't want new users randomly guessing to add new nodes either. How should I start, and how should I do it using Python (and preferably its built-in libraries)? I am running Python 3.8.

Would this be an appropriate question to ask on Stack Overflow? If not, how can I fix it so that it is on-topic? Is there another site that I should ask this question on? I just want to know before posting it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's far too broad, it would help if you'd made a start and had a specific problem

Comment: This is not a good site for "how do I start..." or other very broad type questions. Best to ask these questions on discussion forums and reserve this site for more helping solve much more specific problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's far too broad for Stack Overflow. You need some appropriate code and what you tried to do, not a "please give me all the code I need; thank you" question. Stack Overflow is for very specific questions. If you want a question like that, then go to some discussion forums for help.